# ionic2 Refresher dose not show the pullingIcon and refreshingIcon

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

i'm working on and angularjs2/ionic2 mobile app , and i need to integrate the refresher to make a pull to refresh from [this tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/scroll/Refresher/) .the refresher works fine but i cant get the icons to show's up ? here is my code :

```
<ion-refresher (starting)="doStarting()"
             (refresh)="doRefresh($event, refresher)"
             (pulling)="doPulling($event, amt)" 
              pullingIcon="ion-loading-c"
              pullingText="pull to refresh" 
              refreshingIcon="add" 
              refreshingText="loading" >
</ion-refresher>
```

and here is what i get :

[image]

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set these attributes if you want them to appear:

```
"refreshingIcon" => the icon you want to display when performing a refresh
"refreshingText" => the text you want to display when performing a refresh
```

cf documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/scroll/Refresher/

Comment: check my edits, it's not working. i dont know why ??

Comment: Try to update ionic2 version, I have same issue with my current version because ionic template of the refresher is:
    `<i class="icon" [ngClass]="refreshingIcon"></i>`
so it doesn't works.


In newest version of 1 day ago, the refresher template is:
     `<ion-icon [name]="pullingIcon"></ion-icon>`
So it works.